# Windows 7 Themes on 20.04?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, themes

Are there any Windows 7 themes for Ubuntu 20.04, I know there for sure are some, but I can't find any that are compatible with 20.04.
They are either for too old of a Gnome version or are for Cinnamon and Unity.

Are there any out there or should I get working on one?

Comment: Not sure how strictly you want a Windows theme, but if you just want a classic task bar and start menu, you might want to take Ubuntu MATE for a spin.

Comment: Nah, like a Aero style titlebar theme. I'm working on one right now